# how to call activex control method with multi parameter from java script?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, ffmpeg, activex

I working on a project that requires me to call activex control function from dll using javascript. i am able to call method that has 1 parameter and method with no parameter, but i am not able to call those methods that has multiple parameter. The method that i am trying to call is a put method.

```
STDMETHODIMP CFFMpeg::put_Snapshot(BSTR Path,long newVal){}
```

trying to call this method using following java script code.

```
document.getElementById('GFFMpeg1').snapshot(1) = 'qwerty';
document.getElementById('GFFMpeg1').snapshot(2) = 1;
```

but i am not getting anything.

Please help me by providing appropriate solution to this problem. i've googled it alot but didn't find any solutions.

thanks